# How to split a character vector based on length of a list

Tags: r, vector

I have a character vector like this:

```
a<-c("tanaman","cabai","banget","hama","sakit","tanaman","koramil","nogosari",
    "melaks","ecek","hama","tanaman","padi","ppl","ds","rambun")
```

And I want to split character vector into list based on length of a list like below :

```
split.char<-list(c("tanaman", "cabai"),c("banget", "hama", 
"penyakit", "tanaman"),c("koramil", "nogosari", "melaks", "pengecekan", "hama",
 "tanaman"  , "padi", "ppl", "ds", "rambun"))
```

I'm trying to use `sapply(split.char, length)` for defining length of list `split.char`

```
Length <- sapply(split.char, length)
for(i in Length){
  split(a, Length(i))
 }
```

But I didn't get the desired output and I constantly get this warnings message:

```
1: In split.default(ok, Length) : data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In split.default(ok, Length) : data length is not a multiple of split variable
3: In split.default(ok, Length) : data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
split(x=a, f=rep(seq_along(Length), Length))
```

`f` has to be of the same length as `x` (if it is of length one or a divider of `x` it would be recycled).

Comment: @Ihda: if this answer solves your problem, please mark it with the "check mark" next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `relist` which will give similar structure for 'a' as the 'split.char' (including the `length`)

```
relist(a, skeleton=split.char)
#[[1]]
#[1] "tanaman" "cabai"  

#[[2]]
#[1] "banget"  "hama"    "sakit"   "tanaman"

#[[3]]
#[1] "koramil"  "nogosari" "melaks"   "ecek"     "hama"     "tanaman" 
#[7] "padi"     "ppl"      "ds"       "rambun"
```